# proof of optimality in activity selection

Tags: greedy

Can someone please explain in a not so formal way how the greedy choice is the optimal solution for the activity selection problem?  This is the simplest explanation that I have found but I don't really get it

> *How does Greedy Choice work for Activities sorted according to finish time?
>   Let the given set of activities be S = {1, 2, 3, ..n} and activities be sorted by finish time. The greedy choice is to always pick activity 1. How come the activity 1 always provides one of the optimal solutions. We can prove it by showing that if there is another solution B with the first activity other than 1, then there is also a solution A of the same size with activity 1 as the first activity. Let the first activity selected by B be k, then there always exist A = {B – {k}} U {1}.(Note that the activities in B are independent and k has smallest finishing time among all. Since k is not 1, finish(k) >= finish(1)).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is my understanding of why greedy solution always words:
**Assertion**: If `A` is the greedy choice(starting with 1st activity in the sorted array), then it gives the optimal solution.
**Proof**: Let there be another choice `B` starting with some activity `k` (k != 1 or finishTime(k)>= finishTime(1)) which alone gives the optimal solution.So, `B` does not have the `1`st activity and the following relation could be written between `A` & `B` could be written as:

```
A = {B - {k}} U {1}
```

Here:

1.Sets `A` and `B` are disjoint
 2.Both `A` and `B` have compatible activities in them

Since we conclude that |A|=|B|, therefore activity `A` also gives the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say A is a the optimal solution which starts with 1 if the intervals are S={1,2,3,.....m} and the length of the solution is say n1. If A is not an optimal solution, then there exists another solution B which starts with k!=1 and  finishTime(k)>=finishTime(1), which has length n2.
So, n2>n1.
Now, if we exclude k from solution B then we are left with n2-1 number of elements.
Since, k doesn't overlap with other intervals in B, 1 will also not overlap.
This is because  all intervals in B(excluding k) will have startTime>= finishTime(k)>=finishTime(1).Hence, if we replace k with 1 in B, we still have n2 length. But optimal solution starting with 1 was A with length n1. We are getting n1=n2 , which contradicts n2>n1. Hence Solution starting with 1 is optimal.